# Android Security Exception: package is frozen

Tags: android

Has anyone seen this error before?  App crashes immediately upon opening because it can't start the default Activity.

```
Failure starting process com.xyz
                                                java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.xyz is currently frozen!
                                                    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.checkPackageStartable(PackageManagerService.java:3610)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3791)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3751)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3640)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startSpecificActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1582)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityInnerLocked(ActivityStack.java:2663)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityUncheckedLocked(ActivityStack.java:2215)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeFocusedStackTopActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2066)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeFocusedStackTopActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2056)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppDiedLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:5270)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.removeProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6645)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.killPackageProcessesLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6289)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.forceStopPackageLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6421)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$MainHandler.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:2079)
                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your app maybe running into a "Frozen Frame" (see here: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/frozen.html). This basically occurs if some part of your frame in your app takes longer than 700ms to load. I would suggest looking at the Android Vitals to see what is causing your app to hang. Perhaps you have an infinite loop somewhere. Also, check to see if there are any other error messages besides this one.

Comment: This is not the cause of the given error; see my answer where I trace through where this error message comes from.

Comment: @mhansen, I would take your word for it considering my answer is 4 years old and the Android SDK evolves quickly

Answer (score 1):

Your package is frozen because Android updating your app's package (e.g. with Play Store update, or `adb install`).

The error comes from [PackageManagerService](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java;l=4408;drc=e9fa10ef7a9befa44d73db00c4970d9f26917d3b).

```
            case PACKAGE_STARTABILITY_FROZEN:
                throw new SecurityException("Package " + packageName + " is currently frozen!");
```

`PACKAGE_STARTABILITY_FROZEN` is defined [above](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java;l=439;drc=b45a2ea782074944f79fc388df20b06e01f265f7).

```
    /**
     * Used as the result code of the {@link Computer#getPackageStartability(boolean, String, int,
     * int)} to indicate the given package is <b>not</b> allowed to start because it's currently
     * frozen.
     */
    public static final int PACKAGE_STARTABILITY_FROZEN = 3;
```

This is only ever returned from [ComputerEngine](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/ComputerEngine.java;l=3649;drc=b45a2ea782074944f79fc388df20b06e01f265f7):

```
        if (mFrozenPackages.containsKey(packageName)) {
            return PackageManagerService.PACKAGE_STARTABILITY_FROZEN;
        }
```

Which is set in [`PackageFreezer`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageFreezer.java;l=31;drc=26899cdfee6c19e57390b55df2ee8f541ffbb49a):

```
/**
 * Class that freezes and kills the given package upon creation, and
 * unfreezes it upon closing. This is typically used when doing surgery on
 * app code/data to prevent the app from running while you're working.
 */
final class PackageFreezer implements AutoCloseable {
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this exception when my app had an `abort` on launch within some native code.

Answer (score -1):

Check if setContentView in onCreate is pointing to the correct or an existing layout.

ex:
setContentView(R.layout.activity_LAYOUTNAME);