# React native white screen on launch in debug for android

Tags: android, react-native

Whenever I launch the app I just get a white screen and the react native packager doesn't even start loading in the terminal. I'm running on mac os and I'm running react-native 0.56.0. The project was working fine until I came back to it recently so I'm not sure whats happened. Here's my logcat filtered by Error:

```
09-03 23:59:04.492 1742-1757/system_process E/ActivityManager: Failure starting process com.anyone
    java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.anyone is currently frozen!
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.checkPackageStartable(PackageManagerService.java:3611)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3791)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3751)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3640)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startSpecificActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1582)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityInnerLocked(ActivityStack.java:2663)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityUncheckedLocked(ActivityStack.java:2215)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeFocusedStackTopActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2066)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeFocusedStackTopActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2056)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppDiedLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:5270)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.removeProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6645)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.killPackageProcessesLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6289)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.forceStopPackageLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6421)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$MainHandler.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:2079)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
    09-03 23:59:04.634 2685- 
   2884/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: 
    Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
09-03 23:59:04.636 1585-1818/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl2093892881.tmp: No such file or directory
09-03 23:59:04.981 7831-7831/? E/com.facebook.internal.AttributionIdentifiers: getAttributionIdentifiers should not be called from the main thread
09-03 23:59:05.014 2685-7866/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ContentStoreEUAS: Failed to commit the deferred actions
09-03 23:59:05.016 1926-2099/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.anyone-uMDPquOdtg6BxeTvfE5l_g==/base.apk
09-03 23:59:05.016 1926-2099/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.anyone-uMDPquOdtg6BxeTvfE5l_g==/base.apk
09-03 23:59:05.016 1926-2099/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.anyone-uMDPquOdtg6BxeTvfE5l_g==/base.apk
09-03 23:59:05.016 1926-2099/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.anyone-uMDPquOdtg6BxeTvfE5l_g==/base.apk
09-03 23:59:05.017 1926-2099/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.anyone-uMDPquOdtg6BxeTvfE5l_g==/base.apk
09-03 23:59:07.113 1742-2555/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
09-03 23:59:07.360 1742-2555/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
09-03 23:59:07.614 1742-2555/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
09-03 23:59:07.865 1742-2555/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
09-03 23:59:08.114 1742-2555/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
09-03 23:59:08.314 1742-1915/system_process E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
```

Comment: Did you removing the build folder and doing 'react-native run-android' again?

Comment: @pritam yeh still get a white screen

Comment: Looking at the logs provided, looks like some Android security exception has occurred. See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47643030/android-security-exception-package-is-frozen

Comment: @pritam i've noticed this error as well E/PackageManager.DexOptimizer: Well this is awkward; package com.anyone.MainApplication had UID -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue to do with the react-native-fbsdk node module, updating it to 0.8.0 seemed to work for me https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20938